# Angular Highcharts 10 $digest() iterations reached when object is replaced

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I've been searching for the best approach to this problem for a while and I haven't been able to find a solution. Hopefully someone can steer me into the right direction.

**The problem:**
When I change my dropdown to filter by Gender, my HighCharts directive complains: 
`10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`
I've searched the reason and I think I understand why - something to do with the filter generating a new object and angular being unable to match it to the old? I just can't figure out a workaround!

**In my controller (simplified)**:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.salary_data = [{
      name: 'jenny',
      gender: 'f',
      y: 2000
  }, {
      name: 'bobbler',
      gender: 'm',
      y: 1000
  }, {
      name: 'bobbers',
      gender: 'm',
      y: 2500
  }];

});
```

**In my template:**

```
<select data-ng-model="selectGender" class="form-control" id="selectGender">
  <option value="">- Select all -</option>
  <option value="m">Male</option>
  <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>


<h4>Result</h4>
<pre>{{ salary_data | filter: { gender: selectGender } }}</pre>

<h4>Directive Result</h4>

<salary-chart data="salary_data | filter: {gender: selectGender}"></salary-chart>
```

**In my salaryChart directive:**

```
.directive('salaryChart', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data: '='
    },

    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log(2);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Salary by gender'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: $scope.data
            }]
        });
        $scope.$watch('data', function (newValue) {
            chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
        }, true);
    },

    template: '<div id="container">Error</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(3);

    }
}
```

Edit: Put this into a [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F660x0XPVOBHxa4MK2u3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `filter` in the markup that is causing your `$digest()` errors.
You can work around it by e.g. filtering the data in your controller.

So you could have the following template.

```
<select data-ng-model="gender"
        ng-change="genderChanged()"
        class="form-control">
  <option value=""> - Select all -</option>
  <option value="m">Male</option>
  <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
<salary-chart data="filtered"></salary-chart>
```

And in your controller, handler for `ng-change` (just remember to inject `$filter`).

```
$scope.filtered = $scope.salary_data;
$scope.genderChanged = function() {
  $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.salary_data, {gender: $scope.gender});
};
```

More over, you can move your directive's `controller` code all into `link` function.

Comment: Ah this is brilliant, thank you. Just one question though, in the view you can put multiple filters in i.e `{some_data | filter : oneFilter | filter : anotherFilter}`.  What would you suggest to accommodate more than one filter with `ng-change`?  Plnkr example of what I mean here http://plnkr.co/edit/F660x0XPVOBHxa4MK2u3?p=preview

Comment: You can have one function to handle changes and then apply "a monter" such as `$scope.filtersChanged = function() {
      $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($filter('filter')($scope.salary_data, {gender: $scope.selectGender}), {other: $scope.selectOther});
    };` or have a function accumulating selected filters.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get a result without the data duplicating? How would you handle the changes? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: It's hard to explain, and I'm not entirely sure why or how it is happening. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/yYPDBJAT4Wc83GoiPH2N?p=preview

**This seems just one of the ways to replicate:**
If you choose from the select, gender by `Male`, then other by `Secondary`, then `Primary`, then `-Select All-` it will output two of the same names?

Comment: I'd say because you assigning scope's salary_data to filtered, and therefore manipulating same object. Something like the following should work. `$scope.filtersChanged = function() {
    var data = angular.copy($scope.salary_data);
    var filtered = $filter('filter')(data, {gender: $scope.selectGender});
    filtered = $filter('filter')(filtered, {other: $scope.selectOther});
    $scope.filtered = filtered;
  };
  $scope.filtersChanged();`

Comment: In your case, if you have lots of properties to filter with, you'd be better off creating a custom filter.

Comment: Ended up with the following and works perfectly! 

`$scope.selectionChange = function () {
      var data = angular.copy($scope.salary_data);
      var salaryObj = $scope.salary; // ng-models - salary.gender, salary.other
      $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')(data, salaryObj);
    };`